# Creating a new partition by resizing /dev/sda1

Tags: partitioning

I have the partitions in my computer(11.10) as follows.

- /dev/sda1  mountpoint-root(/) flags-boot 148GB
- /dev/sda2  1GB
- /dev/sda5  1GB

I have 70GB free space on /dev/sda1. I want to create a 10GB partition here **to keep my documents because I'm planning to install 12.04**.

When I try to do it with GParted Partition Utility it doesn't let me unmount /dev/sda1 in order to resize it and create a new partition.

Please give me suggestion on what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GParted doesn't let you unmount the /dev/sda1 partition because Ubuntu is running on /dev/sda1. You can download GParted LiveCD from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-0.18.0-1-i486.iso . Burn it to a CD and boot with it. Now you can resize any partitions because every one of them is unmounted. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't unmount sda1, because you are currently running Ubuntu from it. Try to do with a live CD/flash drive, that should do the trick, but don't forget to backup your data before tampering with gparted and your partition.

Comment: Do you mean to boot with a live CD and then create a new partition in the free space of sda1?

Comment: No, boot into a live CD and then run gparted or whatever program you want to use for resizing your partition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use live usb or CD. You can use gparted for resize your root partition, which is given by default in livecd.
 Open terminal and type **sudo gparted** to open it.

Comment: Or just click on it in the menu...