# Unable to create a new partition for Windows

Tags: 13.04, partitioning

I have only Ubuntu installed and now I need to install Windows 7. I'm using **GParted** for that, however, I can't create a new partition since most of the menu items are disables including `Partition -> New`.

[image]

Comment: @james-okpe-george: From what I can tell, the highest voted answer is still valid for current releases of Ubuntu and Windows apart from EFI stuff..

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to create partitions because you have installed ubuntu in the total size of the disk.  So Gparted can't do the partitioning because the partitions are 'locked' because Ubuntu is running.
So you should make a live CD of ubuntu and boot from that live CD to make the partitions.
OR you can use GParted live CD.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what **you** want and to prepare  your disk for eventual changes in the  future:

1. Boot from an Ubuntu Live DVD or USB.
2. Open the built-in tool `gparted`.
3. Delete the Linux swap partition `sda5`.
4. Delete the extended partition `sda2`.
5. Resize (reduce) the partition `sda1`.
6. Create a new primary partition.
7. Format the partition as swap.
8. Create a new primary partition.
9. Format the partition with NTFS.

**Note 1:**

It is recommended to first install Windows before installing Ubuntu because when you install Windows after Ubuntu the MBR (Master Boot Record) will be overwritten by Windows.

When you nevertheless want to install Windows after you installed Ubuntu you will have to reinstall the GRUB boot loader afterwards to select the OS to boot.

You can reinstall the GRUB boot loader by following the instructions.
Boot from Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

**Note 2:**

`sda` = disk | `sda1` = Ubuntu system partition

**Note 3:**

When you want to have more partitions (later), for instance to store personal data or backups - just create a new extended (logical) partition after completing the steps above.

Comment: Why do you need to delete partitions? You can shrink sda1 from the right and that's it.

Comment: **@Pilot6** and **cl-netbox**.  Please, both: can you use a few more smileys when you post things? **:-)** Both are right: Pilot6's system is easier *to do* for a beginner, cl-netbox's is easier *to understand* for a beginner!  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Pilot6 : I updated the answer to make it more clear why I proposed this setup. :)

Comment: Not sure, but don't new Windows versions automatically want to create another small system-reserved partition? That could make problems if there's no free space left because you already created an NTFS partition for it. And even if it could make one, it would be the 4th primary partition then, no? That would mean there's no chance to create an extended partition and logical volumes any more on an msdos-partitioned drive... What do you think @Fabby?

Comment: @ByteCommander : In this case - NO - OP has Win 7 and the 4th partition must always be extended on mbr table if you want to have further more (because only 4 primary are possible) ... and under extended you can create several logical partitions in case OP wants to have some more ... what you are talking about is happening when you install Win 8 or 10 in efi mode ... my post mainly answers OP's question who wants to install Win 7 after already existing ubuntu. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox I just checked, my Win7 dual-boot installation also created an additional 105MB boot partition. And there's no hint of EFI anywhere, but only good old BIOS.

Comment: @ByteCommander : Anyway ... when OP starts Win installer and had created a new partition under extended before ... then chose this for Win installation everything Win related stuff starts rolling automatically ... he just has to follow instructions ... and this 105 MB thing is the recovery part ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB/LiveDVD and start `gparted`.

Then you will be able to shrink the `sda1` partition and create a new partition using the unallocated space.

After you install Windows you will need to re-install grub.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to shrink of your partition by using GParted as mentioned in this (http://ccm.net/faq/2036-how-to-resize-a-partition-using-gparted-on-linux ) article.
[P.S.: You can use USB instead of CD.]

Then boot up your ubuntu and create a partition for windows.

Note: As mentioned by other users , it is good if you install windows first and ubuntu later.
(After installing windows make sure to rebuild/reinstall GRUB).

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228866/creating-a-new-partition-by-resizing-dev-sda1?rq=1)

Comment: And also dont forget to note down identity numbers of your partitions. ex: Where is your Ubuntu located? (sda2/sda3/sda4)

Comment: Usually sda1 is place for your ubuntu partition.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is install windows from scratch; during the install you can tell it to blow away all existing partitions. Get yourself an external USB hard drive and follow the answer I gave to another question posted in this forum "[How to create an external USB bootable Linux hard drive (without dual-boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348896/upgrading-ubuntu-12-10-to-13-04-using-bootable-usb-alongside-windows-7)